# How can a feature module with providers be imported to another feature module with providers?

Tags: angular

There's a feature module that I kind of like or which I would like to use as a part of my own feature module. The sub-module that I want to include is called `SlimLoadingBarModule`. I want to use it as a base and use it's functionality by providing my own on the top of it. Additionally my whole app can use my `LoadingBarComponent` and `LoadingBarService` and don't need to know about the underlying providers.

So in the end I would like to be able to inject it in my service like this:

```ts
@Injectable()
export class LoadingBarService {

    constructor(private slimLoadingBarService: SlimLoadingBarService) {}

    start() {}

    finish() {}

    /**/ 

}
```

And for that I must somehow include it in my module

```ts
import { NgModule, ModuleWithProviders } from '@angular/core';

import { SlimLoadingBarModule } from 'ng2-slim-loading-bar';

import { LoadingBarComponent } from './loading-bar.component';
import { LoadingBarService } from './loading-bar.service';

@NgModule({
    imports: [ SlimLoadingBarModule.forRoot() ],
    declarations: [ LoadingBarComponent ],
    exports: [ LoadingBarComponent ]
})
export class LoadingBarModule {

    static forRoot(): ModuleWithProviders {
        return {
            ngModule: LoadingBarModule,
            providers: [ LoadingBarService ]
        };
    }

}
```

And the template simply contains the tag for `SlimLoadingBar`

---

**Problem**

Although my own service is singleton throughout my modules, I can't make the `SlimLoadingBarService` to be a singleton. I always get exactly two instances and if I don't inject it into my service I get 1, but then I can't use it.

Additionally I know my service and component is working, as I got these to work once somehow, but I didn't find the modules and imports to be logical enough to keep them like this.

I Have tried various solutions, through `SharedModule`, through `AppModule` but whatever I seem to do, when I try to inject it into my `LoadingBarService` I have 2 instances!

But I feel it shouldn't be impossible for a feature module to use some additional underlying providers and perhaps hiding them from the rest of the application? Is it even possible? If so, then what am I doing wrong?

Comment: Why are you importing `SlimLoadingBarModule` in the `LoadingBarModule`? Modules with `forRoot` are usually meant to be imported in the root (app) module. You can then use it from `LoadingBarService` as you are now.

Comment: @altschuler I understand that with few more changes it would work like this. But I would like to get the option to easily replace SlimLoadingBar or implement our own in case we have the need and time and then we wouldn't have to modify rest of the application, because rest of the application would be dependent on our own service and component. Also I understand that even if the problem is not that big with the loading bar, but for some components this know-how would be even more valuable - to create a wrapper/provider to our application that would always be there with the same functionality.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`forRoot()` should only be used in `AppModule`

```
@NgModule({
    imports: [ SlimLoadingBarModule.forRoot() ],
```

https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/ngmodule.html#!#core-for-root

> Call `forRoot` only in the root application module, `AppModule`. Calling it in any other module, particularly in a lazy loaded module, is contrary to the intent and is likely to produce a runtime error.
>
> Remember to *import* the result; don't add it to any other @NgModule list.

Comment: Thanks for the question edit and the answer. I have researched the `forRoot()` but simply putting everything in `AppModule` is not what I am after at the moment. Also in a way you can consider my `LoadingBarModule` to be the "core" module, that is why I also experimented with the `forRoot()` inside the module. But I still would like to simply create a feature module that secretly uses other modules as dependencies. That's the main goal at the moment.

Comment: I don't think there is anything you can do. You can use modules "secretly" but if you want to use different providers for different situations, this needs to be made explicit by importing different `xxxModule.forRoot()` in the `AppModule`.